# javascript edit: how to disable a css class and add other when current?

Tags: javascript, styling

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.panel').click(function () {
            $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            current = $(this);
            $('#slidewrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 300);     
            return false;
            });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            resizePanel();
            });
        });
    function resizePanel() {
        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();
        mask_width = width * $('.item').length;
        $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);
        $('#slidewrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
        $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
        $('#slidewrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);   
        }
</script>
```

QUESTION: how can i disable "a.panel" styling when the link is current? right now, when the link is current the script adds "selected" styling to the link (see line 5) but it still retains the styling of "a.panel" because it is not disabled.

how can i apply ONLY the styling of "selected" to a current link without the influence of "a.panel"?

**EDIT: ADDITIONAL FEATURE REQUESTED:**

here is some of the html for this script:

```
<a href="#item1" class="panel">item1</a>
<a href="#item2" class="panel">item2</a>
<a href="#item3" class="panel">item3</a>

<div id="slidewrapper">
    <div id="mask">
        <div id="item1" class="item">
            <a name="item1"></a>
            <div class="content">item1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="item2" class="item">
            <a name="item2"></a>
            <div class="content">item2</div>
        </div>
        <div id="item3" class="item">
            <a name="item3"></a>
            <div class="content">item3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when the page loads, the first pane in this slider is open, however, the link is not styled as "selected" until it's clicked on. how can the first link always be styled as "selected"?

Comment: `$(this).removeClass('panel')` ? If this isn't what you're looking for, please further clarify your question.

Comment: <a href="#item1" class="panel selected">item1</a> but you will have the problem again that you will have both styles applied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $aPanel = $('a.panel');
    $aPanel.click(function () {
        $aPanel.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).removeClass('panel');
        current = $(this);
        $('#slidewrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 300);     
        return false;
        });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
        });
    });
function resizePanel() {
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();
    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;
    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);
    $('#slidewrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#slidewrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);   
    }
```

Explanation: added a new line, `var $aPanel = $("a.panel");` to "cache" the jQuery selector at the DOM ready event, so that you can add and remove classes without fear, knowing that the same anchor elements will be in the `$aPanel` variable.

Comment: thanks paul, you answered my question perfectly and it does just what i asked. however, there is a glitch:

when you click on the link the original style is disabled and the new style is applied perfectly. however, when you click on another link, that first link you clicked is now completely style-less because it now doesn't have a class to associate with. the visited link goes rogue. somehow, we need to re-attribute the "a.panel" class to the visited link.

Comment: try adding $aPanel.addClass('panel'); after $aPanel.removeClass('selected');

Comment: works perfectly. paul and akzen, you guys are awesome. i wish i could repay the favor!

Comment: FOLLOW-UP QUESTION: so the script is working perfectly but i'd like to add an additional feature. added to EDIT in original post.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to remove the "panel" style from your element, like:

```
$(this).removeClass('panel')
```

But I'm not sure if this is what you want, because when you click another panel later the call to `$('a.panel').removeClass('selected');` will fail, because it doesn't have the `panel` class anymore.

Why not make 2 classes `selected` and `unselected` which you differentiate in your stylesheet. Then you can user the panel class for associating event handlers and other things.

Alternatively change the style from `selected` so that it overrides the properties from `panel` that you doesn't want.

**Edit:** Changed answer, see comment

Comment: I actually don't believe that's correct. Unless she/he was using `.on` with the delegation stuff, the handlers should all be still attached, no matter what classes are added or removed.

Comment: I think you are correct, thx for the info. although it's still problematically, see updated answer

Comment: Yeah, changed my answer, made it so that it should surmount the problem you caught. Good catch.

Comment: akzen t, that's actually exactly what happened